# Use google.maps in Azure Mobile Service NodeJS

Tags: node.js, google-maps, azure, azure-mobile-services

I'm working with Azure mobile service - NodeJS backend
and I want to check a polygon map if it contains a point.
How to use google map library on it ? Or no way ?

--Thanks--

```
    var customerLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    var area = serviceParsed[0];
    /*example: [{"type":"POLYGON","id":null,"geometry":[[[21.070767653166016,105.80863952636719],[21.01180841534327,105.77705383300781],[21.031036817912042,105.87455749511719]]]}] */
    var triangleCoords = [];
    if (area.type == "POLYGON") {
      for (var j = 0; j < area.geometry[0].length; j++) {
        triangleCoords.push({
          "lat": area.geometry[0][j][0],
          "lng": area.geometry[0][j][1]
        });
      };
    } else { }
    var bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({ paths: triangleCoords });
    if (google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(customerLatLng, bermudaTriangle)) {
      filteredResults.push(item.Id);
    }
```

Comment: Just to verify, you want to use the Google Maps SDK within the Node backend?  In what context?  Can you post a complete sample?

Comment: Yes,as the example above, I want to use google maps to check if a polygon area contains a point (location) in Mobile Services API (Node JS).
But I'm getting error "google is not defined"

Comment: To confirm, you are using Azure Mobile Services or Azure Mobile Apps?

Comment: @Gary Liu - MSFT: I'm using Azure Mobile Services

Comment: Have you installed the module as mentioned at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-store-scripts-source-control/ ?

Comment: No, It hasn't been installed

Comment: If I setup sources control for mobile services, can I install the extension library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have researched more about Azure mobile service. We can install other nodejs modules to package.json of mobile service.
So, this is steps:

1. Set up source control for Mobile service (example: GIT)
2. Clone API code to client folder (use SourceTree)
3. Install module needs to use
4. Commit package.json to server

For example:
 1. npm install geolib
 2. package.json file after step 3

```
"engines": {
    "node": ">= 0.8.19"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "geolib": "^2.0.21",
    "point-in-polygon": "^1.0.1"
  },
```

3. Commit package.json
4. In api file:

   var geolib= required("geolib");
   // use as in https://www.npmjs.com/package/geolib